# Is tagging/checking in on google map through android and iphone app possible?

Tags: iphone, android

My client presented me with this requirement:

**Another icon label Places is where users can report where they are so friends and family would be able to locate the user.**

I'm new to iPhone and android programming, I don't need to ask you code for this.
I want to know that whether or not this thing is possible in iPhone and android native application.
Although I am pretty sure yet want to confirm with experts before committing with client.

It would be much better if you provide any sample/example application.

Thanks all.
Guru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, yes. No problem.

Smartphones don't automatically give out their location to anyone. Traditionally You have to share the location. In other words you need to get your phone to report to central server somewhere your location (using the phone to get your latitude and longitude).
With this location you can then push it to other users or have other users fetch it. (I'm ignoring the fact that you will need security)

I would recommend, at least for testing purposes and getting used to location sharing concepts, looking at Google's Latitude [API](http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/)s. This is available to iPhone and Android. This does all the 'hard work' of location sharing, syncing etc.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks Tim,
+1 For exact solution!!

:)

I hope I would get success!!